# Combine every second row into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have simple table1 with

```
columnA   columnB
A          10
A          20
B          15
B          50
C          2
C          40
```

Goal to see this results

```
columnA   columnB   Newcolumn
A          10         20
B          15         50  
C          2          40
```

My query

```
SELECT * FROM   
(
    SELECT 
        ColumnA, ColumnB
    FROM 
       table1
        
) t 
PIVOT(
    COUNT(ColumnA) 
    FOR ColumnB IN (
        [Newcolumn],  - Not sure about this Newcolumn
     )
) AS pivot_table;
```

This is the error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
> Error converting data type nvarchar to float.
> Msg 473, Level 16, State 1, Line 13
> The incorrect value "Newcolumn" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.
> The incorrect value "newcolumne" is supplied in the PIVOT operator.

Comment: Is it min and max, or do you have some other way to tell SQL Server that `A, 10` comes before `A, 20`?

Comment: no min or max , it could be any numbers

Comment: So how do you tell SQL Server which one is "first"? And what if there are 3 rows or 60 rows or just 1 row for a given `columnA`?

Comment: I think you can use row 1 , 2 , 4 , 5, 6  in order I guess

Comment: Correct, columna might have same 2 or more

Comment: Rows don't have "in order" - a table is an unordered bag of rows unless you specify an order. If you don't care, that's fine, but if you want a specific order you need some other way (e.g. another column) to determine what "first" means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- guaranteed to be ordered by column B:

  ```
  ;WITH src AS 
  (
    SELECT columnA, columnB, rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY columnA ORDER BY columnB)
    FROM dbo.table1
  )
  SELECT columnA, columnB = [1], newcolumn = [2]
  FROM src
  PIVOT 
  (
    MAX(columnB) FOR rn IN ([1],[2])
  ) AS p;
  ```

  Output:

  | columnA | columnB | newcolumn |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | A | 10 | 20 |
  | B | 15 | 50 |
  | C | 2 | 40 |
- arbitrary / "I don't care":

  ```
  ;WITH src AS 
  (
    SELECT columnA, columnB, rn = ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY columnA ORDER BY @@SPID)
    FROM dbo.table1
  )
  SELECT columnA, columnB = [1], newcolumn = [2]
  FROM src
  PIVOT 
  (
    MAX(columnB) FOR rn IN ([1],[2])
  ) AS p;
  ```

  Output here is the same, but that is just a coincidence:

  | columnA | columnB | newcolumn |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | A | 10 | 20 |
  | B | 15 | 50 |
  | C | 2 | 40 |
- example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6a91dd0bee30f864cc8b00d62831bfee)